# Calculate difference between two date in DATE_RFC2822 format

Tags: php, date

i have to `calculat`e the difference between two date in this format:

`Fri, 29 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200`

But i can't use date_diff() function..how can i do that?

With this code

```
<?php
    $now = date(DATE_RFC2822);
    $now = date_create($now);
    $feed_date = date_create($feeds[$y-1]); //value of $feeds[$y-1] = Fri, 29 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200
    $feed_date = date_diff($now,$feed_date) ?>
```

I get this:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be
>   converted to string in blablabla

[EDIT] it won't work..if i use this i get always 0 minutes

```
$now = date(DATE_RFC2822);
    $now = date_create($now);
    $feed_date = date_create($feeds[$y-1]);
    $data_post = date_diff($now,$feed_date);
     ?>
      <?php echo $data_post->format('%R%a minutes'); ?>
```

Comment: *It isn't a duplicate because the other question can't solve my problem* - yes it can, just mung your dates into DateTime objects, compared them, and format the output.

Comment: Use the `format()` method on the `DateInterval` to format it before printing, e.g. `echo $feed_date->format('%R%a days');`. http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: @JeroenNoten it doesn't work..

Comment: Try `echo $data_post->format('%R%i minutes');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date_diff()` function accepts `DateTime` objects and returns a `DateInterval` object:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('Fri, 29 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200');
$datetime2 = date_create('Sat, 30 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Note that this is the procedural style, you can also use the object oriented style if you prefer:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('Fri, 29 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('Sat, 30 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in

Comment: You should not print `$interval` immediatly, use the `format()` method on the `DateInterval` to format it before printing. http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Answer (score 0):

You could just parse the date before using date_diff:

```
$date1 = date_create("Fri, 22 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200");
$date2 = date_create("Fri, 29 Apr 2016 12:27:29 +0200");
$diff  = date_diff($date1, $date2);
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in

Comment: You should not print `$diff` immediatly, use the `format()` method on the `DateInterval` to format it before printing, e.g. `echo $diff->format('%R%a days');`. http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php